# How to prmisify .native function of mongo into bluebird promise?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, sails.js, bluebird

I am using sails and connecting two databases mysql and mongo with my app, I am stuck where I have to promisify the .native functions of sailsjs mongo adapter.

```
Activities.native(function(err, activities) {
  if (err) return res.serverError(err);
  activities.find({}).toArray(function (err, results) {
        if (err){
          return err;
        }else{
          console.log(results);
          return results;
        }

     });
});
```

I want this function to be promisified with bluebird . any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap that inside a promise and continue using promise logic like this:

```
function doTheNativeQuery() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        Activities.native(function (err, activities) {
            if (err) return reject(err);

            activities.find({}).toArray(function (err, results) {
                if (err) return reject(err);

                resolve(results);
            });
        });
    });
}


doTheNativeQuery().then() ....
```